While executing Insert Statement in Snowflake getting error
I was doing Badge 3 in snowflake university and getting error. ESS-DABW Badge 3: Data Application Builders Workshop: Lesson 5: Pending Orders App Improvements   Perfecting the ORDERS Table Definition.
Below is my code in Smoothies Database public schema and orders table.
alter table SMOOTHIES.PUBLIC.ORDERS 
add column order_uid integer --adds the column
default smoothies.public.order_seq.nextval  --sets the value of the column to sequence
constraint order_uid unique enforced; --makes sure there is always a unique value in the column

create or replace table smoothies.public.orders (
       order_uid integer default smoothies.public.order_seq.nextval,
       order_filled boolean default false,
       name_on_order varchar(100),
       ingredients varchar(200),
       constraint order_uid unique (order_uid),
       order_ts timestamp_ltz default current_timestamp()
);

Insert statement that is not working:
insert into smoothies.public.orders 
values ('Guava Cantaloupe Elderberries ', 'Abhi');

Error message

Insert value list does not match column list expecting 5 but got 2

My Streamlit code:
# Import python packages
import streamlit as st
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col
from snowflake.snowpark.context import get_active_session

# Write directly to the app
st.title(":cup_with_straw: Customize Your Smoothie! :cup_with_straw:")
st.write(
    """Choose the fruits you want in your custom Smoothie!
    """
)

name_on_order= st.text_input('Name on Smoothie')
st.write('The name on your Smoothie will be:', name_on_order)


session= get_active_session()
my_dataframe = session.table("smoothies.public.fruit_options").select(col('Fruit_name'))
#st.dataframe(data=my_dataframe, use_container_width=True)
ingredients_list = st.multiselect('Choose up to 5 ingredients:', my_dataframe
)

if ingredients_list:
    #st.write(ingredients_list)
    #st.text(ingredients_list)
    ingredients_string= ''
    for fruit_chosen in ingredients_list:
        ingredients_string+=fruit_chosen + ' '
    #st.write(ingredients_string)

    my_insert_stmt = """ insert into smoothies.public.orders
        values ('""" + ingredients_string + """','""" + name_on_order+ """')"""

    #st.write(my_insert_stmt)
    #st.stop()
    time_to_insert= st.button('Submit Order')
    if time_to_insert:
        session.sql(my_insert_stmt).collect()
        st.success('Your Smoothie is ordered!', icon="✅")

Streamlit App Image
Streamlit App Error Image

Typically, unless one is providing all 5 values to the insert, the columns must be specified if less (or if there are columns without any table default should have values), so try with: my_insert_stmt = """ insert into smoothies.public.orders (ingredients, name_on_order) values (...

If you don't provide an explicit list of columns, the values will be matched to all the columns, and as the error says - you have five columns but only two values.
Assuming you meant to leave the default values for the columns that have them, you can explicitly list the columns without the default values:
insert into smoothies.public.orders 
(name_on_order, ingredients) -- Here
values ('Guava Cantaloupe Elderberries ', 'Abhi');

